# how do I iterate over a "gslist" in Python?

Tags: python, glib

Let's say I get a glib `gpointer` to a glib `gslist` and would like to iterate over the latter, how would I do it?

I don't even know how to get to the `gslist` with the `gpointer` for starters!

**Update**: I found a workaround - the python bindings in this instance wasn't complete so I had to find another solution.

Comment: Can you provide more context? As far as I know, most GTK/Glib functions use Python lists instead of GSLists in their Python bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is `glib` exposed to Python in your application? Via SWIG, ctypes or something else?

You should basically use `glib`'s own functions to iterate over a list. Something like `g_slist_foreach`. Just pass it the pointer and its other parameters to do the job. Again, this heavily depends on how you access `glib` in your Python application.